# Create groups through Microsoft Graph API works but files and notebook not created for the group

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi, microsoft-graph-api

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/groups
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Content:
{"description": "UnifiedGroup",
 "displayName": "UnifiedGroup",
 "mailEnabled": false,
 "mailNickname": "UnifiedGroup",
 "securityEnabled": true
}
```

Above `http` `post` creates the group but the corresponding files or notebook is not created. I can see the following error

**ERROR**

> Something happened We tried connecting all the pipes but it didn't
>   work quite right. Refresh to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unified groups need to be created with groupTypes property containing "Unified" value. They also can't be security enabled. Please use the following request content to create the group:

```
{
     "description": "UnifiedGroup",
     "displayName": "UnifiedGroup",
     "mailEnabled": false,
     "mailNickname": "UnifiedGroup",
     "securityEnabled": false,
     "groupTypes" : [ "Unified" ]
}
```

Comment: @Prasad FYI: regular security groups created through the API don't have any associated content.  Marek is rightly pointing out that groups which contain content (aka Office 365 group or Unified groups) need additional info as part of the POST.

Comment: I believe that the mailEnabled property needs to be set to true for unified group creation.

Answer (score -1):

> corresponding files or notebook is not created.

This may be because the related OneDrive for Business group is not created, which usually takes a while (up to 24 hours).